# how can i notify a specific users

Tags: laravel, post, comments

here is my **AdsController.php**

```
public function save(Request $request)
{
      $this ->validate($request,[
        'object'=>'required',
        'description'=>'string',

    ]);

    $ads = new Ad;
     $current_user=Auth::user();
    $ads->object = $request->input('object');
    $ads->description = $request->input('description');


    $ads->save();

    $users = User::where(("id","!=",$current_user->id ) || ("admin","=",1 ))->get(); 

    foreach ($users as $user) {

        $user->notify(new NewAd($current_user, $ads));
    }

    return redirect('listads') ;
}
```

I want to post an ad to the admin only but i have an error

Please help me

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Is the error from the above code, or some other code you tried? If it's from other code, you will be better showing that code, so that people can suggest changes to fix the error.

Comment: To my understanding... `!=` wont work.. Use `<>` which means doesn't equal

Comment: i get a syntax error i want to notify only the  admin

Answer (score 0):

You made a simple mistake of your query builder, the conditions should be chained as follow:

```
$users = User::where('id', '<>', $current_user->id)->where('admin', 1)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use where condition like this

```
$users = User::where("id","!=",$current_user->id)
          ->orWhere("admin",1 )->get();
```